# Writing a linked list to binary file(C)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, binaryfiles, fwrite

So I have set up a linked list and read data from a file, done some calculation and manipulation and now I want to store the new list into a binary file.

Here is my struct setup:

```
typedef struct Comp{
    char name[5];
    char node1[5], node2[5];
    float value;    //value
}ComponentType;

typedef struct ListNodeT{

    ComponentType Component;
    float voltage, power, current;
    struct ListNodeT *nextPtr;
}ListNodeType;
```

In a separate function I am trying to write to a a file:

```
FILE *filePtr;

char fileName[13] = "SaveData.bin";
filePtr = fopen(fileName, "wb");
int index = 0;

while (CircuitData != NULL)
{
    fwrite(CircuitData, sizeof(ListNodeType), 1, filePtr);
    CircuitData = CircuitData->nextPtr;
    index++;
}
```

The above code is not working so now my question is, can I write to the file using a single fwrite(CircuitData, sizeof(ListNodeType), 1, filePtr) or should I write each component separately as follows:

```
fwrite(CircuitData->Component.name, sizeof(CircuitData->Component.name), 1, filePtr);
```

How should I be doing this? My second question is, how would I read this binary file again back into the Struct?

Comment: Did you check the value of `filePtr` after opening the file? May be its `NULL`.

Comment: Well I can open the binary file and see that something was written to it.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? (segfault, strange values, unexpected result)?

Comment: you may want to have an separator between the single CircuitData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to use the pointer-values from a file in a new invocation of the program, so you'll need to do something about that. You could make a copy before printing and zero-out the pointer; then when reading, you'll need to assign the correct pointer values for the newly allocated structs.

I'd probably read them with a recursive function. Something like this:

```
ListNodeType *read_list_from_file (FILE *fileptr) {
    ListNodeType node;
    ListNodeType *nodeptr;
    if (fread(&node, sizeof(node), 1, fileptr) == sizeof(node)) {
        nodeptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
        //TODO: handle malloc failure
        memcpy(nodeptr, &node, sizeof(node);
        nodeptr->nextPtr = read_list_from_file(fileptr);
        return nodeptr;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not? You char arrays and floats will be fine. It's just that the pointer values will be meaningless because they refer to storage in another process that doesn't exist or isn't accessible.

Comment: There may also be cross-platform portability issues with performing a simple `write` of the binary object. But for saving/loading on one machine, it should be fine.

Comment: @luserdroog what are expected portability problems? I'm working on storing ADT's in a file myself. It would be great to know what to avoid. Thanks.

Comment: @zubergu Machines may have have different byte endianness or they might expect different structure padding due to different alignment restrictions.

Comment: There are 2 major classes of byte-ordering conventions called "Little-endian" and "Big-endian". Data being moved from a machine of one class to a machine of the other class must be converted. `float` is practically guaranteed to be IEEE 754 32-bit, but the C standards have been reluctant to make this a requirement for implementations. So there may be machines where a `float` isn't exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you intend to transmit the file and allow it to be read in by another computer, you may have the problem with byte representation (f.e. the float values). One approach is, to convert the floats to a string representation on write() and convert it back on read().

Better would be to use a well defined format (like CSV or xml)